# Personal Campaign Pages only visible on front end when logged into back end

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, personal-campaign-pages

Using WP 4.6.1 and Civi 4.7.13. I am trying to create a set of PCP's for staff members for our year end fundraising campaign. I can successfully create a PCP from the link provided by the Contribution Page using a browser in which I am not logged into WP/Civi. In another browser, I am logged into WP/Civi and approve the PCP and am able to see that PCP by clicking the link in the Civi PCP list. However, if I log out or try to use that link in another browser in which I am not logged into WP/Civi I get an error stating that the PCP is not available but I can donate using the donation page form. What am I missing?

Thanks,
e.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the permissions and roles? If not you may find useful the following documentation [Default Permissions and Roles](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Default+Permissions+and+Roles)

Comment: Thanks - I double checked against the Civi WP demo and Anonymous permissions are the same as my site but the demo PCP works. I assume this would be an anonymous permission given that anyone should be able to see a PCP. Any other ideas?